# boost graph library example six degrees of Kevin Bacon: what is Vertex() in the example

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to learn Boost Graph library and came across an example called "Six Degrees of Kevin Bacon". Here is the URL https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/graph/doc/kevin_bacon.html

In that example, I see:

```
...
boost::tie(pos, inserted) = actors.insert(std::make_pair(actors_name, Vertex()));
...
```

What does `Vertex()` refer to?

I see an alias called `Vertex` a few lines above the `Vertex()` like below but I am not understanding what `Vertex()` is for:

```
typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
```

Can someone please help me understand this one? I am new to Boost and feel like I am already lost!
The documentation is very difficult to read through and understand.

Thanks.

Comment: You can insert two things into a graph: a vertex and an edge.  So the actor is a vertex and the edges are people they have starred with.  So the example will insert all the actors as vertexes and all the connections between them as edges.

Answer (score 2):

The [Vertex (graph theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(graph_theory))  is used to record an actor's connections to other actors. They are directly connected if they have appeared in the same movie.

The Vertex used in the example is described here: [`boost::graph_traits<Graph>`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/graph/doc/graph_traits.html)

This line:

```
boost::tie(pos, inserted) = actors.insert(std::make_pair(actors_name, Vertex()));
```

tries to insert a `pair` with the actor's name and a default constructed (empty) `Vertex`. If it fails (`inserted==false`), it's because the actor was already present and `pos` will be pointing at the existing `pair` with a `Vertex` that already has at least one connection. If it succeeds `pos` will point at the newly inserted `pair` with an empty `Vertex`.

The `add_edge` step later on is what connects the two actors. When the file has been processed you'll have a graph of how all the actors in the file are connected (via edges).

Comment: Hi Ted, thank you so much. vertices and edges are clear to me. My question was why do we need the Vertex() function in this line? boost::tie(pos, inserted) = actors.insert(std::make_pair(actors_name, Vertex()));

Comment: @user3512999 Oh, that's not a function. It default constructs a `Vertex` that is put in the `pair`. It'll start with a Vertex that has no edges if the actor isn't already in the graph.

Comment: Thank you Ted. I see that now.